# Read file.csv (two columns; x and y) then calculate cumulative moving average of second column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wanted to read my CSV file first.
https://github.com/hamzaal014/file/blob/main/file.csv

the .csv file contains two columns X and Y
here is my script:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import csv

origin_data = open("file.csv", "r")
dato = list(csv.reader(origin_data, delimiter=","))
print(dato)

rowcount  = 0
#iterating through the whole file
for row in dato:
  rowcount+= 1
#printing the result
#_ print("Number of lines present:-", rowcount)
print(rowcount)

dati = df(dato, columns=['x', 'y'])

window = 6
roll_avg = dati.rolling(window).mean()

roll_avg_cumulative = dati['y'].cumsum()/np.arange(1, 25)
print(roll_avg_cumulative)
```

but my script is not working ???

Error --------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/haz/miniconda39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 163, in _na_arithmetic_op
    result = func(left, right)
  File "/home/haz/miniconda39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 239, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/home/haz/miniconda39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 128, in _evaluate_numexpr
    result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
  File "/home/haz/miniconda39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 69, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading from a file you are returned strings. This is the source of your problem since the strings are never converted into numbers. You can fix it by:

```py
dati = df(dato, columns=['x', 'y'], dtype_float)
```

If it is helpful to you I would also like to poit out a few things that may improve your code:

- you are using pandas as your container for data so I would suggest using the pandas functions to convert a CSV file to a DataFrame instead of doing it manually (do it by using `pandas.read_csv`)
- the row count can be easily calculated with the `len` operator without needing to iterate over all rows
- please stick to the more widely used import aliases (`import pandas as pd`) instead of creating your own. This will help your code be more readable to everyone else

So your code can become:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dati = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=",", dtype=float, names=["x", "y"])
rowcount = len(dati)

window = 6
roll_avg = dati.rolling(window).mean()

roll_avg_cumulative = dati["y"].cumsum() / np.arange(1, 25)
print(roll_avg_cumulative)
```

Comment: Dear @Matteo Zanoni can i use ??
**roll_avg_cumulative = dati["y"].cumsum() / np.arange(1, len(dati))**
in case the .csv file contains more than one line (unknown)

Comment: Yes of course, just be carefull to match the dimensions. Since you start the arange from 1 you have to go one extra number: `roll_avg_cumulative = dati["y"].cumsum() / np.arange(1, len(dati) + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

**What went wrong in your code:**

- All vals are loaded as `str`.

**Simple way**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

dati = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)

window = 6
roll_avg = dati.rolling(window).mean()
print(dati[1].cumsum())

roll_avg_cumulative = dati[1].cumsum()/np.arange(1, 25)
print(roll_avg_cumulative)
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear **@Matteo Zanoni** and **@Bhanuchander Udhayakumar** both solutions work very well.